# DevExpress and Syncfusion

Tags: devexpress, syncfusion

Very simple question. I was working with devexpress controls on my VS installation and now I have been asked to look at Syncfusion. Has anyone got both installed side by side and are there any issues with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Syncfusion and Devexpress integrate with Visual Studio through the Visual Studio [extension](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/extend/) model and should not have any conflicts. I have come across our customers using both without any issues in Visual Studio.